# How to animate form elements in vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a login screen I want to animate. There are about 3 groups of form elements on the page. My goal is to have the form elements appear one div key group at a time as fade-ins 1 second apart. I'm only seeing the first group. How can I get the div groups to appear after each other?

```
  <form class="form-signin" @submit.prevent="login">
```

```
      <transition name="fade">
        <div key="1">
          <img class="mb-4" src="../assets/logo1.png" height="189px">
          <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">WELCOME</h1>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
        </div>

        <div key="2">
          <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Name</label>
          <input id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" autofocus="" type="text" v-model="username">
          <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
          <input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password" v-model="password">
        </div>

        <div key="3">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-5" type="submit">Sign in</button>
          <p>Don't have an account? <router-link to="/signup" class="-link">Sign Up</router-link></p>
          <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-{{ getYear() }} </p>
        </div>
      </transition>
  </form>

</form>
```

and my css for the fade

```
  .fade {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 1s;
  }
  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to  {
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

Comment: you want  key="1" ,  key="2" ,  key="3" to appear one by one when the component is rendered in browser, is it?

Comment: imagine a form with three elements. each form element fading into view until all three can be seen. like that.

Comment: check my answer @jessi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<transition>` can animate only one element. But, you can make use of multiple `<transition>` elements. In Your case you could use 3 `<transition>` elements to reach your final result.

Since you are looking for animation on page load, you could make use of `appear` attribute that is available with `<transition>` element. `appear` will trigger the animation once page is loaded.

if you don't have `appear` attribute, you need make use of `v-if` to initiate the animation

if you have `appear` attribute then the animation under `*-enter-active` will be triggered by vuejs by default after page load. You can also override the default behavior. Check the reference url i provided at the end of this answer.

**Sample code is below**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="fade1" appear>
      <div class="fadecontent">
        hello world1
      </div>
    </transition>
    <transition name="fade2" appear>
      <div class="fadecontent">
        hello world2
      </div>
    </transition>
    <transition name="fade3" appear>
      <div class="fadecontent">
        hello world3
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .fadecontent{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding:20px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .fade1-enter,.fade2-enter,.fade3-enter{
    transform: translateX(20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .fade1-enter-active{
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  .fade2-enter-active{
    transition: all 1s ease 1s;
  }
  .fade3-enter-active{
    transition: all 1s ease 2s;
  }

  .fade1-leave-active,.fade2-leave-active,.fade3-leave-active{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  .fade1-leave-active{
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  .fade2-leave-active{
    transition: all 1s ease 1s;
  }
  .fade3-leave-active{
    transition: all 1s ease 2s;
  } 
</style>
```

This is not the only approach to get to this result. You can also make use of plain `html css js` to animate this same scenario.

**Reference**

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render

Comment: This is wonderful @divine . This solution is also very Vue-ish so I'd like to go with this one. It works very well. Thank you very much.

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did in my app.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      interval: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.showBlocs()
  },
  methods: {
    showBlocs() {
      let els = document.querySelectorAll('.bloc')
      console.log(els[1])
      let i = 0
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        els[i].classList.add('slide-bottom-fade-in')
        i++
        if (i === els.length) {
          clearInterval(this.interval)
        }
      }, 200)

    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
})
```

```css
.bloc {
  background: teal;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slide-bottom-fade-in {
  animation: slide-bottom-fade-in ease 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: slide-bottom-fade-in ease 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: slide-bottom-fade-in ease 1s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: slide-bottom-fade-in ease 1s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: slide-bottom-fade-in ease 1s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*IE 10+*/
  opacity: 0;
  opacity: 1\9;
}

@keyframes slide-bottom-fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, -40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-bottom-fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, -40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-bottom-fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes slide-bottom-fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translate(0px, -40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes slide-bottom-fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, -40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

.slide-left-fade-in {
  animation: slide-left-fade-in ease 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: slide-left-fade-in ease 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: slide-left-fade-in ease 1s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: slide-left-fade-in ease 1s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: slide-left-fade-in ease 1s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*IE 10+*/
  opacity: 0;
  opacity: 1\9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="bloc">

  </div>
  <div class="bloc">

  </div>
  <div class="bloc">

  </div>
</div>
```